# Update Gedit to 2.32 being able to use SyncTeX on 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, gedit, evince

I found this nice [demonstration](http://jaliste.blogspot.com/2010/08/synctex-support-in-gnome-232.html) showing the use of SyncTeX with Gedit and evince. I would like to use this nice feature but my Ubuntu Natty Narwhal (11.04) does not have Gedit in the version of 2.32.

```
kon@pc:~$ gedit --version 
gedit - Version 2.30.4
kon@pc:~$ evince --version
GNOME Document Viewer 2.32.0
```

How do I update Gedit being able to use SyncTeX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve this problem. Now I'm using TexMaker(v 2.2.1), it has the sync feature already build in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided mentions that the SyncTex is a new feature of **Gnome 2.32** and not Gedit 2.32.
You can check which gnome version you have by executing `gnome-session --version`.

To enable the SyncTex you will have to install the gedit extra plugins by executing `sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins`. After installation open Gedit and enable the plugin from the Edit -> Preferences -> Plugins menu.

Comment: Hey @yossile, if I execute the the command, it produces the message "Unknown option --version". But my Gnome says that I have version 2.32.1 installed (System -> About Gnome).

Comment: @kon please see my corrected answer

Comment: I installed gedit-plugins but the plugin tab does not show synctex plugin. The version of the installed package gedit-plugins is 2.30. I had a look at the version of [2.32](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gedit-plugins/2.32/) and the synctex plugin is there.